# How to install PHPunit in a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm trying to set up PHPunit in a Laravel project (which is being running in a Linux VM using Vagrant and VirtualBox).  I've added PHPunit to `composer.json` and run `composer install` and `composer update`, and yet nothing is working.  Running `phpunit` from the command line does nothing.  (Nor does `php phpunit` or `php phpunit.phar`.)

How do I get PHPunit to run my tests?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must now run it using:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 4):

Install phpunit globally and then can you can use it with just `phpunit` command in your local project instead of `vendor/bin/phpunit`
(your composer/vendor/bin has to be in system path)

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

or you can add following alias in your VM and then you can run it within your project directory with just `phpunit` command

```
alias phpunit='vendor/bin/phpunit'
```